# MariaDB/MySQL Function Select into returns more than one row, 3 variables

Tags: mysql, variables, insert-into

I am currently studying SQL and we're using MariaDB and Toad for MySQL as our graphic editor. Currently, we have to create a function that returns 3 different variables.

```
SELECT ourFunction(c.dni), v.CV, cl.nom_color
INTO @var_age, @var_cv, @var_color
    FROM vehicle v
    INNER JOIN client c
      ON c.dni=v.dni
    INNER JOIN color cl
      ON v.color=cl.cod_color
```

We need each variable to give us an exact value so we can use it on another function. The problem is currently that we can't get the results we want on the variable.

Client is 1:N to Vehicle

Vehicle is 1:1 to Color

ourFunction calculates the age of the client. This is what it does:

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE FUNCTION ourFunction(dni varchar(9))
  RETURNS tinyint(3)
  BEGIN
   select TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, birth_date, CURDATE()) AS age
INTO @age
FROM client c
WHERE c.dni=dni;
RETURN @age;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Of the multitple vehicles and colours which one do you want? First, last,all, pink blue....Oh and you cannot add multiple values to a variable.